# Class 'evseevnn\Cassandra\Database' not found

Tags: php, apache

Estoy intentando llamar a la clase 'evseevnn\Cassandra\Database' para ese espacio de nombres sin éxito. Para ello me baso en un caso similar con la misma arquitectura donde sí lo consigo.

La arquitectura es la siguiente,

```
myproject\
    |
    application\
        |
        core\
            controller.php
    ----------
    ----------
        |
        vendor\
            |
            evseevnn\
                |
                cassandra\
                    |
                    src\
                        Database.php
```

Este es el fragmento de código de controller.php,

```
use \evseevnn\Cassandra\Database as Database;
//require '../vendor/src/evseevnn/cassandra/Database.php';

class Controller
{

    public $db = null;

    public $model = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->openDatabaseConnection();
        ......
    }

    private function openDatabaseConnection()
    {
        $nodes = [
            DB_HOST
        ];

        $this->db = new Database($nodes, DB_DEFAULT_KEYSPACE);
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    .......
    .......
}
```

y para el archivo Database.php quedaría como sigue,

```
namespace evseevnn\Cassandra;

use ......
use ......

class Database {

    ......
    ......
}
```

¿Por que, tratándose de la misma arquitectura y desplegada en el mismo servidor WAMP, en un caso funciona y en el otro no?

Comment: Cuál es el que funciona y el que no?

Answer (score 1):

Este es el archivo composer.json que utilicé para instalar el driver,

```
{
    "name": "root/testclient",
    "require": {
        "evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary": "dev-master"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Evseev Nikolay",
            "email": "evseevnn@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Y el archivo controller.php quedaría de la siguiente forma,

```
require APP . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use evseevnn\Cassandra\Database as Database;

class Controller
{

    ------
    ------

    private function openDatabaseConnection()
    {
        $nodes = [
            DB_HOST
        ];

        $this->db = new Database($nodes, DB_DEFAULT_KEYSPACE);
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    ------
}
```

Ahora ya me funciona correctamente.